# extract certain integers from a string and then normalize it

Tags: python

I wish to normalize the integers within a string. Example:

```
string = ["There is a discount of 45% on the sales in the shopping mall", "60percent discount will be given to any purchase made"]
```

I am wondering whether will this be possible to do.

```
a = []
for x in string:
    xsplit = x.split()
    for xx in xsplit:
        if xx.isdigit():
            newxx = xx/100
            a.append(newxx)
```

My above codes are very expensive and too many loops. I wish to find a way to achieve my expected output while also stay shorter codes. Is that even possible? I will keep updating my new test codes here. Please do assist me.

I received error:

```
unsupported operand type(s) for /: 'str' and 'int'
```

My expected output should be:

```
[0.45, 0.6]
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use `re.findall`:

```
import re
res = []
for s in string:
    res.extend(re.findall('\d+', s))
res = [int(r)/100 for r in res]
```

Output:

```
[0.45, 0.6]
```

Comment: Thank you so much Sir. This is really helpful! Thank you

Comment: I need to wait for the cool down of 4minutes to mark it as answer

Comment: By the way sir, is there a way to include the % into the list also? I will do the ress of deleting it. because sometimes, our sentence will not be so clear might be like "80people" then this will be very wrong right?

Comment: @kingkongmanoftheworldinchaos So do you want your output to be like `['0.45%', '0.6%']`? In that case, change the last line into `res = ['{}%'.format(int(r)/100) for r in res]`